# Disable editing for graphics

Tags: graphics, interactive

I am creating an interactive graphics that plots points on the canvas, and allows the user to move around the points:

```mathematica
DynamicModule[
 {pt1 = {-2, 1}, pt2 = {2, 2}, pt3 = {2, -2}}
 ,
 Framed@Graphics[
   {Locator[Dynamic[pt1]],
    Locator[Dynamic[pt2]],
    Locator[Dynamic[pt3]],
    Dynamic[BezierCurve[{pt1, pt2, pt3}]]
    }
   , PlotRange -> 3]
 ]
```

It works fine, but I noticed that if one misses a bit the click with the mouse to move one of the points, Mathematica mistakenly suggests to edit the Graphics object. It happens during the point movement in the following screenshot (Note the tooltip "Double Click to edit"):

[image]

Is there any way to disable editing for Graphics?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- `Deploy` seems work.

```
DynamicModule[{pt1 = {-2, 1}, pt2 = {2, 2}, pt3 = {2, -2}}, 
 Deploy@Dynamic@
   Framed@Graphics[{Locator[Dynamic@pt1], Locator[Dynamic@pt2], 
      Locator[Dynamic@pt3], Dynamic@BezierCurve[{pt1, pt2, pt3}]}, 
     PlotRange -> 3]]
```

- Another way is use `LocatorPane`.

```
DynamicModule[{pts = {{-2, 1}, {2, 2}, {2, -2}}},
 LocatorPane[Dynamic@pts, 
  Dynamic@Graphics[BezierCurve@pts, PlotRange -> 3, Frame -> True, 
    FrameTicks -> None]]]
```

Comment: Thank you very much indeed. `Deloy` does just that. But, now the user doesn't have the [change of mouse appearance](https://i.stack.imgur.com/52iY3.png) when hovering over the dynamic object. Is there anyway to retain the "default" behaviour?

Comment: @tush that seems like an interesting question that you should make into a new question post entirely!

Comment: All right then!